# Url to right route description

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I have url like this:

`/#/administration/counters/1`

How can I get route description in React component. For this url the right route description is:

`/administration/counters/:counterId`

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use this.props.location.pathname in any of the component to get the current pathname.

Comment: It gives me current url I need actual route descriptiom with :counterId

Answer (score 0):

You could use `this.props.params.counterId`
This param is available in your route component, your children, by default, don't have this param.

Answer (score 0):

I need exact url description which is in this case

`/administration/counters/:counterId`